# Python Quickest Method to Iteratively Slice List of Date Strings

Tags: python, string, date

I have a long list of date strings, e.g. ['2011-01-01', '2015-05-05'].  In the list of n strings, I need to select the i-th string and find the latest date of strings i:n.  I can do this, but the process is slow, taking hours for a list of hundreds of thousands of strings.  **What code optimizations am I missing?**  Sample code is below.

```
import numpy as np

d = np.random.choice(xrange(0, 1000), size=100000, replace=True).tolist()
d = [str(item) for item in d]

total = len(d)
for i in xrange(total):
    this_slice = d[i:total]
    greatest = max(this_slice)
    if i % 1000 == 0:  # To track progress
        print i
```

That examples goes fast enough.  Using actual date strings, not numeric strings as in the example, is much slower.  I have timed the execution precisely, but it seems to take about 30-60 minutes for 600,000 date strings.

Here is a more precise representation of the code for my data:

```
import pandas as pd

i = 0
rows = df.shape[0]
for date in df['date']:  # date is 'YYYY-MM-DD'
   this_slice = df['date'][i:rows]
   df['new_date'] = max(this_slice)
   if i % 1000 == 0:  # To track progress
       print i
   i += 0
```

I have converted the date strings to datetime objects, made them integers (first removed the '-'), and the speed is no quicker.  There must be a faster way to write this code!

Comment: can you use a database?

Comment: Looks like you are working with pandas. Right?

Comment: Shove them into SQLite and use your favorite orm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm will be a lot more efficient if you compute from end to begin so you can reuse maximum value:

```
import numpy as np

d = np.random.choice(xrange(0, 1000), size=100000, replace=True).tolist()
d = [str(item) for item in d]

total = len(d)
greatest = d[total-1]
for i in reversed(xrange(total)):
    greatest = max(greatest, d[i])
    if i % 1000 == 0:  # To track progress
        print i
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas should speed this up:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date_string': ['2017-01-01', '2011-12-01', '2015-05-05', '2010-10-01']})
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date_string)
df['new_date'] = df.dates

for i in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'new_date'] = df.dates[i:].max()
```

Now `df` looks like this:

```
  date_string      dates   new_date
0  2017-01-01 2017-01-01 2017-01-01
1  2011-12-01 2011-12-01 2015-05-05
2  2015-05-05 2015-05-05 2015-05-05
3  2010-10-01 2010-10-01 2010-10-01
```

Comment: I was using pandas, sorry that was not clear in the first draft of my question.  pandas is still slow in this loop because it slices from the top.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're iterating over the list in the outer loop in strict sequence, you can keep the index of the maximal date in the remaining slice until you pass, saving you from calling max every time. N.B. argmax requires ints or floats, so convert your dates beforehand

```
 rows = df.shape[0]
 max_remaining_idx = -1
 for i in xrange(rows):  # date is 'YYYY-MM-DD'
     if i > max_remaining_idx:
        max_remaining_idx = df['date'][i:].argmax()
     df['new_date'] = df['date'][max_remaining_idx]
     if i % 1000 == 0:  # To track progress
         print i
```

Comment: Actually, @Oliver Pellier-Cuit's method better.